# How do I loop through data from an API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, object

I'm trying to learn how to grab data several levels in to JSON data coming from APIs, and I'm getting confused on how to do so. For example, I'm trying to create a random meal generator that displays a list of ingredients that is in an array of recipes, but also, the ingredient names I need are in their own object.

I'm not sure how to set up my loop to loop through the list and grab the ingredient name to display it. Here is my example so far: [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/?template=XWjRpoV)

Thanks!

```js
document.getElementById("shuffle").addEventListener('click', getImage);


async function getImage() {
const response = await fetch("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/random?number=1", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "{redacted}",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
    }
})
const data = await response.json();
  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = data.recipes[0]["title"];
  document.getElementById('instructions').innerHTML = data.recipes[0]["instructions"];
  document.getElementById('image').src = data.recipes[0]["image"];
  show(data); 
}

 getImage()
 .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    });


function show(data) { 
  let list = 
      `
      <ul></ul>
      `
    for (let ingredient of data.recipes) { 
        list += `  
    <li>${ingredient.extendedIngredients[0].originalString}</li>        
`; 
    }
  
  document.getElementById('ingredients').innerHTML = list;
}
```

```css
.recipe {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
.recipe__directions {
  display: flex;
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 2rem;
}
.recipe__instructions {
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.recipe__image {
  width: 25vw;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="recipe">
      <h1>Feeling hungry?</h1>
      <h2>Get a random meal by clicking below</h2>
      <button class="button mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored" id="shuffle">Find a meal</button>
      <h3 id="title" class="recipe__title"></h3>
      <div id="ingredients" class="recipe__ingredients"></div>
      
      <div class="recipe__directions">
        <p id="instructions" class="recipe__instructions"></p>
        <img id="image" class="recipe__image" src="" alt="">
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code is already looking pretty good, but without seeing a sample response from the API it's hard to say what you need to do.

Comment: (On a general note, it's not a good idea to post API keys on the Internet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `forEach()` to loop through each `extendedIngredients` property.

```
function show(data) { 
  let list = 
      `
      <ul></ul>
      `
  data.recipes[0].extendedIngredients.forEach( function(ingredient){
        list += `  
    <li>${ingredient.originalString}</li>        
`; 
    });
  
  document.getElementById('ingredients').innerHTML = list;
}
```

You were on the right track, but not deep enough. The for loop you wrote is iterating over each `recipes`, not each `extendedIngredients`. There is only one `recipes` so you access it with key `[0]`.

```
function show(data) { 
  let list = 
      `
      <ul></ul>
      `
    for (let ingredient of data.recipes[0].extendedIngredients) { 
        list += `  
    <li>${ingredient.originalString}</li>        
`; 
    }
  
  document.getElementById('ingredients').innerHTML = list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- if you look at json structure will se that extendedIngredients are an array so, you can loop for each of them
- You are getting only one recipe at time so no need a loop there...

you can change the loop to:

```js
   for (let ingredient of data.recipes[0].extendedIngredients) { // loop over ingredients of first recipe
            list += `  
        <li>${ingredient.originalString}</li>        
    `; 
        }
```

```js
document.getElementById("shuffle").addEventListener('click', getImage);


async function getImage() {
const response = await fetch("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/random?number=1", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "",
        "x-rapidapi-host": ""
    }
})
const data = await response.json();
  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = data.recipes[0]["title"];
  document.getElementById('instructions').innerHTML = data.recipes[0]["instructions"];
  document.getElementById('image').src = data.recipes[0]["image"];
  show(data); 
}

 getImage()
 .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    });


function show(data) { 
  let list = 
      `
      <ul></ul>
      `
    for (let ingredient of data.recipes[0].extendedIngredients) { // loop over ingredients of first recipe
        list += `  
    <li>${ingredient.originalString}</li>        
`; 
    }
  
  document.getElementById('ingredients').innerHTML = list;
}
```

```css
.recipe {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
.recipe__directions {
  display: flex;
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 2rem;
}
.recipe__instructions {
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.recipe__image {
  width: 25vw;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="recipe">
      <h1>Feeling hungry?</h1>
      <h2>Get a random meal by clicking below</h2>
      <button class="button mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored" id="shuffle">Find a meal</button>
      <h3 id="title" class="recipe__title"></h3>
      <div id="ingredients" class="recipe__ingredients"></div>
      
      <div class="recipe__directions">
        <p id="instructions" class="recipe__instructions"></p>
        <img id="image" class="recipe__image" src="" alt="">
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```